# Java help. How to draw images

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, java-2d

Hi I'm starting to work on this project where I need to have a picture (map of the US) and then I need to circles of different sizes on the map at different locations. Something like this: http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=110997398

What's the best way to go about doing it? I've never dealt with Java 2-d but I'm guessing that's what I should use.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Java 2D should be exactly what you need, and [Sun has some really good tutorials for it](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/index.html).

If you search around you can find lots of Java 2D game tutorials ([like this one](http://www.zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/)) as well.  They might be a little more interesting to learn from, and they demonstrate the same features that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you don't have to be to accurate, because a circle on a sphere (aka 'world') doesn't look like a circle on 2-D and a 2-D circle is something else in world coordinates.

If it's just for fun and training, you could continue with drawing 2-D circles on the projected map but if you need to draw 'real' circles on the world, you should use a library with the power to transform a shape to any projection.

Last time I used [OpenMap](http://openmap.bbn.com/) and it was pretty easy.